# Insert data into SQL table from XML file stored in varchar(max) column of another table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

My table Table1.State varchar(max) column contains an XML file looking something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='MyObject.xsl'?>
<MyProperties>
<SortingState
  Before="[{&quot;Sorting&quot;:1
           ,&quot;Type&quot;:4
           ,&quot;Enabled&quot;:false}]" 
  After="[{&quot;Sorting&quot;:2
           ,&quot;Type&quot;:0
           ,&quot;Enabled&quot;:true}]" />
<Appearance
  Before="[{&quot;Transparent&quot;:1
           ,&quot;Color&quot;:Red
           ,&quot;Border&quot;:10}]" 
   After="[{&quot;Transparent&quot;:0
           ,&quot;Color&quot;:Blue
           ,&quot;Border&quot;:8}]]" />
</MyProperties>
```

I wonder how I can read this Table1.State column into a temp table or table variable so the file is transformed into a table like this:

```
SortingState Before    Sorting        1
SortingState Before    Type           4 
SortingState Before    Enabled        false 
SortingState After     Sorting        2
SortingState After     Type           0 
SortingState After     Enabled        true
Appearance   Before    Transparent    1
Appearance   Before    Color          Red 
Appearance   Before    Border         10 
Appearance   After     Transparent    0
Appearance   After     Color          Blue 
Appearance   After     Border         8
```

Comment: That's a good question. JSON doesn't follow YAML rules, so it would be a lot easier if the JSON embedded in your `@Before` and `@After` attributes properly quoted the non-numeric values `Red` and `Blue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright this is not the prettiest solution, but it produces your requested output. I create a `varchar(max)` variable `@XmlText` using your provided XML (with exception of updating a few single quotes to double single quotes in order to be contained in the string literal). Cast it in a variable to `xml` data type, then parse:

```
DECLARE @XmlText varchar(max) = 
'<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet type=''text/xsl'' href=''MyObject.xsl''?>
<MyProperties>
<SortingState
  Before="[{&quot;Sorting&quot;:1
           ,&quot;Type&quot;:4
           ,&quot;Enabled&quot;:false}]" 
  After="[{&quot;Sorting&quot;:2
           ,&quot;Type&quot;:0
           ,&quot;Enabled&quot;:true}]" />
<Appearance
  Before="[{&quot;Transparent&quot;:1
           ,&quot;Color&quot;:Red
           ,&quot;Border&quot;:10}]" 
   After="[{&quot;Transparent&quot;:0
           ,&quot;Color&quot;:Blue
           ,&quot;Border&quot;:8}]]" />
</MyProperties>'; 

DECLARE @Xml xml = CAST(@XmlText AS xml); 
SELECT 
    my_properties_nodes.xml_frag.value('fn:local-name(.)','varchar(20)') AS Column1
    ,first_level_attributes.xml_frag.value('local-name(.)','varchar(10)') AS Column2
    ,SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), CHARINDEX('"', RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('"', RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), CHARINDEX('"', RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), 1) + 1) - CHARINDEX('"', RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), 1) - 1) AS Column3
    ,CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('}', RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), 1) > 1
            THEN SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), CHARINDEX(':', RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('}', RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), 1) - CHARINDEX(':', RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), 1) - 1)
        ELSE RIGHT(RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value))) - CHARINDEX(':', RTRIM(LTRIM(ss.value)), 1)) 
    END AS Column4
FROM 
    @Xml.nodes('/MyProperties/*') AS my_properties_nodes(xml_frag)
    CROSS APPLY my_properties_nodes.xml_frag.nodes('@*') AS first_level_attributes(xml_frag) 
    CROSS APPLY string_split(first_level_attributes.xml_frag.value('.','varchar(max)'), ',') AS ss;
```

The query starts with a row for each child element directly under the `MyProperties` element, increase rows to one for each attribute at the first child element, then increase the rows again by splitting the the value of the attribute (using `string_split` by a comma. Then I just manually parse the values out. `Column3` is parsing between the first and second `"`. `Column4` is parsing between the first `:` and the end of the string, or between the first `:` and the first `}` depending on whether or not the string contains a `}` character.

Hopefully this helps.

Also, you can use this from a table containing this text as by using an `OUTER APPLY` to convert your `varchar(max)` column to `xml`. Then use `CROSS APPLY` to the first `@Xml.nodes('/MyProperties/*') AS my_properties_nodes(xml_frag)` and replacing `@Xml` with a reference to your converted xml value:

```
.......
FROM 
    MyTable AS tbl_a
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT CAST(tbl_a.VarcharMaxColumn AS xml) AS ConvertedXml) AS cast_xml
    CROSS APPLY cast_xml.ConvertedXml.nodes('/MyProperties/*') AS my_properties_nodes(xml_frag)
.......
```